# regex is not working with lookup in monodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to search name from user_info but this query is not working nor giving me any issue .
Here full_search is variable which store the the text which user type in input box

```
var full_search =  "John"; // req.body.search 

Wallet.aggregate([ { $match:{"user_info.name":{"$regex": full_search, "$options": "i"}}} ,
{ $lookup:{
              from: "users",
              localField: "user_id",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "user_info"
            }},
  {$project:{ "user_info.name":1}} ]
```

Comment: The syntax is invalid. Each aggregation pipeline stage is it's own document. i.e there is a `{` missing from the front of `$match` and the `$lookup`. You should use a text editor that detects your syntax errors.

Comment: `Wallet.aggregate([{ $match:{"user_info.name":{"$regex": full_search, "$options": "i"} } }, { $lookup:{ from: "users", localField: "user_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "user_info" }}, {$project:{ "user_info.name":1} }])`

Comment: Why edit to copy the syntax in the comment? You incorrect syntax was the likely problem originally, and if you copied the syntax and still don't get what you want then you have a **new problem**. How about stating what exactly you think the problem is. **Not working** is not a sufficient explanation since it **works** for everyone else in the world as far as we can tell from the very limited information here.